# feed python output to sqlite as input sql stement

Tags: org-babel

I would like to feed python output to sqlite input as below:

```
#+NAME: sqlcmd
#+begin_src python :results output
print("select * from tablename")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: sqlcmd
: select * from tablename

#+begin_src sqlite :db /media/sf_work/a.db -header -column :var sqlcmd=sqlcmd :results output
sqcmd
#+end_src
```

It not work now.

What's proper way to use sql command output from python script?

Answer (score 0):

Read <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(org)Noweb Reference Syntax`

Example:

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results verbatim
'(+ 1 2)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: foo
: (+ 1 2)

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes :results verbatim
<<foo()>>
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 3
```